# Java: Generating tile based circles of any size

Tags: java, grid, geometry, tile

[image]

Above is a pattern I have been trying to figure out how to generate for quite some time now.  I pretty much want to input the radius of the circle into a method and have it return an array with the proper values in it. (Ex. 0 = darkest, 1 = less dark, 2 = less less dark, etc)

My problem is is that I have no idea how this could be done mathematically.  Every time the radius increases, the edges of the bounding square are eroded even more.  I do not see a clear pattern in change between sizes 3, 4, 5, and so on.  Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Here is some info I came up with:

- Radius of 3 means (x-2,y-2) (x-2, y-1) and (x-1, y-2) are not changed on the left side and every other respective corner.
- Radius of 4 means (x-3, y-1) (x-3, y-2) (x-3,y-3) (x-2, y-2) (x-2, y-3) and (x-1, y-3) are not changed on the left side and every other respective corner.
- x center point - (Radius - 1) = left, x center point + (Radius - 1) = right
- y center point - (Radius - 1) = top, y center point - (Radius - 1) = bottom

Comment: Just draw one circle. Chop it up in quarters. And move the quarters about. It's a good bit simpler to find an algorithm (or built-in function!) to draw a normal circle.

Comment: Well thats the thing, I have to be able to "draw" the circle into and array of data.  I am wondering how I could go about drawing a square then chop the corners off

Comment: Why? This is covered in any primer on how to ["*raster* circles"](http://groups.csail.mit.edu/graphics/classes/6.837/F98/Lecture6/circle.html). Also you could utilize the Java built-in drawing support and extract the data from an Image (or whatever it is these days).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is extremely confusing, not least which due to the fact that your example doesn't look at all like a circle.  @pst is exactly right.  You can draw a circle to an offscreen buffer and then use that for your output.

For instance,

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * @author Nicholas Dunn
 * @date 4/21/12
 */
public class CircleGridCreator {

    /**
     *
     * @param radius
     * @return 2 dimensional array in row major order, where entry is 0 if not part
     * of circle, or 1 otherwise
     */
    public static int[][] getGrid(int radius) {
        if (radius < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid radius " + radius);
        }

        BufferedImage buffer = new BufferedImage(radius*2, radius*2, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Color c = Color.BLUE;
        Graphics2D context = buffer.createGraphics();
        context.setColor(c);
        context.fillOval(0, 0, radius * 2, radius * 2);

        int[][] results = new int[radius*2][radius*2];
        for (int row = 0; row < radius*2; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < radius*2; col++) {
                if (buffer.getRGB(col, row) == c.getRGB()) {
                    results[row][col] = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {

            int[][] grid = getGrid(i);

            for (int[] row : grid) {
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[1, 1]
[1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Not perfect but it should get you going.